# InvalidClassException on Serializable objects

Tags: java, serialization, glassfish, entity, eclipselink

I'm having some problems integrating with my colleague's code.

He has an entity class, let's call it `FooEntity`:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@Table(name = "...")
public class FooEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = ...;
    ...

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "OBJBYTES")
    private Serializable objBytes;

    ...
}
```

He is creating his DTO object

```
public class FooDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = ...;

    ...

    private Serializable obj;
    ...
}
```

via helper class

```
public class FooHelper {

    ...

    public static Serializable createSBar() {
        Bar bar = generateBar();
        Serializable sBar = bar;
        return sBar;
    }

    ...

}
```

that creates a `Bar` object that implements `Serializable` interface:

```
public class Bar implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = ...;

    private String myString;
    private byte[] myBytes;
}
```

In his DAO, he's creating entity object from his DTO object and saving it to database and retrieving entity object and mapping it to a DTO object.

On retrieving the list of entries that match certain criteria via [`Query#getResultList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getResultList%28%29) an `InvalidClassException` is thrown with this message:

```
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-66] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Could not deserialize object from byte array.
Internal Exception: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.my.package.Bar; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 4849912519109332230, local class serialVersionUID = -1015090985675288072
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[objBytes-->FOO_TABLE.OBJBYTES]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.my.package.entity.FooEntity --> [DatabaseTable(FOO_TABLE)])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException.notDeserializable(DescriptorException.java:1218)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.converters.SerializedObjectConverter.convertDataValueToObjectValue(SerializedObjectConverter.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.foundation.AbstractDirectMapping.getAttributeValue(AbstractDirectMapping.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.foundation.AbstractDirectMapping.valueFromRow(AbstractDirectMapping.java:1299)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.foundation.AbstractDirectMapping.buildCloneFromRow(AbstractDirectMapping.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildAttributesIntoWorkingCopyClone(ObjectBuilder.java:1548)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildWorkingCopyCloneFromRow(ObjectBuilder.java:1694)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObjectInUnitOfWork(ObjectBuilder.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.buildObject(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.registerResultInUnitOfWork(ReadObjectQuery.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadObjectQuery.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1081)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:844)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1040)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.execute(ReadObjectQuery.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1128)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2871)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1516)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1498)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.NoIndirectionPolicy.valueFromQuery(NoIndirectionPolicy.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.valueFromRowInternal(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:2098)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.valueFromRowInternal(OneToOneMapping.java:1695)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.valueFromRow(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:1987)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.buildCloneFromRow(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildAttributesIntoWorkingCopyClone(ObjectBuilder.java:1548)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildWorkingCopyCloneFromRow(ObjectBuilder.java:1694)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObjectInUnitOfWork(ObjectBuilder.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.buildObject(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.registerResultInUnitOfWork(ReadAllQuery.java:769)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1081)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:844)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1040)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1128)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2871)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1516)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1498)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1463)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.executeReadQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getResultList(EJBQueryImpl.java:742)
    at com.my.package.dao.FooDAO.getRange(FooDAO.java:584)
    ...
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.my.package.Bar; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 4849912519109332230, local class serialVersionUID = -1015090985675288072
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:560)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1599)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1494)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1748)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1327)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.converters.SerializedObjectConverter.convertDataValueToObjectValue(SerializedObjectConverter.java:70)
    ... 165 more
```

It may also be relevant to note that when deploying the app in Glassfish 3.1.2.2, the following messages are displayed in the log:

```
[#|2014-06-05T12:39:01.301+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.classloading.com.sun.enterprise.loader|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|com.my.package.entity.FooEntity actually got transformed|#]

[#|2014-06-05T12:39:01.310+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.classloading.com.sun.enterprise.loader|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|com.my.package.entity.Foo2Entity actually got transformed|#]

[#|2014-06-05T12:39:01.316+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.classloading.com.sun.enterprise.loader|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|com.my.package.entity.Foo3Entity actually got transformed|#]

[#|2014-06-05T12:39:01.322+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.classloading.com.sun.enterprise.loader|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|com.my.package.entity.Foo4Entity actually got transformed|#]

[#|2014-06-05T12:39:01.327+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.classloading.com.sun.enterprise.loader|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|com.my.package.entity.Foo5Entity actually got transformed|#]

[#|2014-06-05T12:39:01.332+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.classloading.com.sun.enterprise.loader|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|com.my.package.entity.Foo6Entity actually got transformed|#]

[#|2014-06-05T12:39:01.337+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.classloading.com.sun.enterprise.loader|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|com.my.package.entity.Foo7Entity actually got transformed|#]

[#|2014-06-05T12:39:01.345+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.classloading.com.sun.enterprise.loader|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|com.my.package.entity.Foo8Entity actually got transformed|#]
```

Could someone explain why this exception is occurring and how to solve it?
Also, I'm assuming it's not a good practice to use entity objects as JAXB objects, right?

Comment: Did you or your colleague change the `serialVersionUID` in between?

Comment: OMG, he had records in database for entities with different UIDs...

Please post an answer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message shows:

> Internal Exception: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.my.package.Bar;
>   local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID =
>   4849912519109332230, local class serialVersionUID =
>   -1015090985675288072

There seem to be two different `serialVersionUIDs`, this seems to cause the error. You have to find out why there are different values, maybe the value was changed in the meantime.